# Oracle view performance

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view that runs a fairly complex query on a large amount of data. When I run the the view for all data it takes a couple minutes, which is fine. My problem is when I am reducing the result set by either joining to another table with less rows or using a where clause with subquery it still takes the full 2 minutes to run. What I found is that if I specify the id as text in the where clause the query will return very fast. To illustrate what I mean:

Given the query below returns a single row with the result 1234:

```
select id from mytable where external_id = 1;
```

If I query my view for all rows it takes about 2 minutes to execute, which is expected

```
Select * from  my_view ;
```

If I query my view using the following query it will still take the full 2 minutes to execute:

```
Select * from  my_view v where v.id = (select id from mytable where external_id = 1);
```

But if I specify the ID right in the query it will return in less then a second

```
Select * from  my_view v where v.id =1234;
```

Since both queries will always return the same result is their anyway I can instruct oracle to run the sub query first so that it can filter the view in the same manner as the second query? (Note: joining to mytable yields the same result. I choose to use a subquery in the example because I thought it was clearer).

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully your question, but maybe the [MO_MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF51095) will help you.